# Calculating $\phi^{*}(\omega)$ and $\phi^{*}(d\omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $\omega = xdx +2zdy-ydz$
and 
$\phi:R^2 \to R^3, (u,v) \to (uv,u^2,3u+v)$

How do I determine $\phi^*(\omega)$ and $\phi^*(d\omega)$?

I calculated $d\omega= -xdx \wedge dy -3 dy \wedge dz$

Thanks for any hint or an example for a part of the term

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130251/problem-with-pullback-calculation?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

$\phi^*(\omega) = uv d(uv) + 2(3u +v)d(u^2) - u^2d(3u +v)$
Hope now you can solve this.

Also $\phi^*(d \omega) = d(\phi^*(\omega)) $ .So this can help you to solve the second one too by using the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually $\phi^*(\omega)= (u^3v^2+9u^2+4uv)du +(u^4v-u^2)dv$